# objective c, NSMutableArray: indexOfObject

Tags: objective-c

```
int k = 0;
k = [myArray  indexOfObject:_endNode];
```

I only have a few objects added to the array and _endNode isn't one of them.

I expect my k value to be -1. But, my k on the second line gives me a value of 21787887.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's actually [`NSNotFound`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW3), which is defined as `NSIntegerMax`.

This, by the way, is quite explicit [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB).

Comment: Actually, how would I access constants from the auto complete box.      Like I can see methods from NSMutableArray, by doing [NSMutableArray ...], but the constants don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

This information may help you,

```
I think there is no DATA in you _endNode so its returning the junk value for the "k"
```

Please check the values of _endNode.....

Answer (score 0):

It's actually `NSNotFound` ans defined as `NSIntegerMax`

---

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray arrayWithObject:_endNode] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:Myarray];
int k;
k=[array indexOfObject:_endNode];
```