# NSMutableArray indexOfObject returning an extremely large number

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray returning an extremely large index?

```
po [masterArray count] < returns "2"

NSUInteger theIndex = [masterArray indexOfObject:validateEnrollmentStatus];
```

The above returns an NSUInteger of "2147483647"? I am not sure how that is possible or what is going on?  masterArray clearly on has to item in given the count method call in the debug console.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [objective c, NSMutableArray: indexOfObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794383/objective-c-nsmutablearray-indexofobject)

Answer (score 19):

That's the value for `NSNotFound`. This means the object you are looking for isn't in the array.

Comment: It is returning -1. But since NSUInteger is unsigned, -1 is actually 2147483647. This is why you use the constant `NSNotFound`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. `validateEnrollmentStatus` is not present in `masterArray`. So you can probably add a check for that before you try to get the `indexOfObject`.

```
    NSUInteger theIndex = 0;

    if ([masterArray containsObject:validateEnrollmentStatus]) {
        theIndex = [masterArray indexOfObject:validateEnrollmentStatus];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ is not present in masterArray", validateEnrollmentStatus);
    }
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to simply call indexOfObject and check the result. One lookup versus two.

Comment: I dont think it is more efficient if you just call indexOfObject. If that was the case, apple would have never made a method 'containsObject' and nobody would have used it right? Even with the the check for NSNotFound, it would take the same number of lines to achieve that.

Comment: Both methods need to do a search through the array for the object. In the case where the object exists and it happens to be the last object, you end of doing two full scans of the array. `containsObject` has its place. But for this, just call `indexOfObject:` and check the result.